# Parse API: What happens when there are multiple objects with the same object id ?

Tags: parse-platform, http-delete

In the parse [guide](http://parseplatform.org/docs/rest/guide/#objects-updating-objects) under updating objects, it's shown how we can update an object with the object-id.

It doesn't really state what would happen if there are multiple objects with the same id. If I send a delete request for an object-id does the newest object get deleted ?

Would the Parse Api have any problem handling the vagueness of this request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Object IDs are unique and are automatically assigned when you create a new object. There shouldn't be any clashes.